# Why do exceptions occur when using reflection in jdk17?

Tags: java, reflection, java-threads, java-17

I need to obtain the value in the current ThreadLocal through reflection

but there is an exception about "*module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module *"

And after adding the following configuration to the jvm startup parameters, the exception was resolved

```
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
```

**My questions :**
**1. Why the objects defined by myself, no error reported**

```
  public class Record implements Serializable {
  private String name;
  // ....
  }
```

**2. Is there any other way besides adding startup parameters in the jvm**

---

```
java -version

java version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+8-LTS-111)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+8-LTS-111, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My Code

```
public class TT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        Field threadLocalsField = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("threadLocals");
        threadLocalsField.setAccessible(true);
        Object threadLocals = threadLocalsField.get(thread);
        System.out.println(threadLocals);
    }

}
```

the detail error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap java.lang.Thread.threadLocals accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @327471b5
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.moan.message.base.remote.service.helper.TT.main(TT.java:19)
```

One useful way: add vm option

```
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: What does 'why the objects defined by myself, no error reported' mean? Your question is unclear. Note that the answer is likely to be a disappointing "Because JDK17 just broke this stuff, theres nothing you can do other than add the `--add-opens` VM options, or find a way to do this without reflection.

Comment: An unnamed module (as you are using here) opens all packages to all modules. `java.base` does not. That is why you don't get an exception when you use deep reflection on a type in an unnamed module.

Comment: “Is there any other way besides adding startup parameters in the jvm”  No.  This is by design:  programs are not allowed to mess with the internals of classes which don’t belong to them.  In fact, you are playing with fire by relying on a private field of a Java SE class, because later versions of Java may change or remove it without any warning.  The whole point of object-oriented design is that applications are not supposed to be concerned with internal implementation of libraries, only with public methods and the guarantees made in their documentation.

Comment: @rzwitserloot  I had defined the class named 'Record' and 'implements Serializable',  When I obtain private field in 'Record' through reflection, I will not report an error .   
I think Johannes Kuhn has provided a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn in this specific case, it doesn’t matter whether the OP is using an unnamed module or a named module. *Within the same module*, such reflective access is always allowed.

Comment: @Holger Fine, a module opens all its packages to itself.